# JavaScript validation problems

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code `document.write("<h1>" + Date() + "<\/h1>");` I need to use `\` in the closing `h1` tag to validate my HTML page. Whats the purpose of using `\` in the tag.

Comment: It defines that it is the end of the `<h1>` block, instead of the start of a new one...

Comment: yes it is used to escape special characters but i dont think so you need it here. Your code should run without '\'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no formal error in your JavaScript code. The problem is probably that you have it inside an HTML document, in a `script` element, and then `</h1>` may become a problem (depending on HTML version and software used). At the HTML level, the `\` breaks the construct so that it won’t be parsed as an end tag. In a JavaScript literal, `\/` means just the same as `/` (you can “escape” a normal character, too).

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character is usually used to escape "special" characters.  You shouldn't need it in there.

Comment: if not using, getting HTML validation warning `The 2 characters "</" have been detected in a wrong place.`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be writing DOM elements using `document.write`, this overwrites any existing DOM elements that were in the HTML document.

The second slash (backslash) that you've used shouldn't be needed. Take a look at this example for both of my points:

http://jsfiddle.net/SrQKt/7/

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, only `/script` needs to be escaped `\/script`

In HTML validation move the JS to an external file to allow validation.

Using innerHTML is sligthly better - 
DOM manipulation will also do the job inline or in external files:

```
var header = document.createElement("h1");
header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Date()))
someContainer.appendChild(header);
```

for example